# Mirror a Longtext Field using a Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, custom-object, long-text-area

I am pretty new to salesforce development and was assigned a task to mirror a long text field from a parent object to a child object. I tried using a formula but I guess you can't use a long text field in a formula. 
What would be the best way to mirror all of the long text fields on a parent object, to a child object. I tried to write a trigger but I received an error that I couldn't store a value in the long text field of the child object. 
Is there a better or different way I should be doing this. 
Here's the code for my trigger,

```
trigger updateField on Object_1(after insert, after update)
{

   for(Object_1 a : Trigger.new)
   {
     if(a.Description != Object_2__C.Description_Mirror__c)

     {

       Object_2__C.Description_Mirror__c  = a.Description; 

     }

   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that `Object_1` is your parent object and `Object_2` is your child object, and that you haven't made any changes to the code of this trigger other than altering the object names. If that's the case, the issue lies here:

```
 if(a.Description != Object_2__C.Description_Mirror__c) {
   Object_2__C.Description_Mirror__c  = a.Description;
```

Both occurrences of `Object_2__C.Description_Mirror__c` are references to the schema_: the *definition* of the field, not to the storage for the field on some specific record of `Object_2__c`.

To achieve this objective effectively, you'll need to query for child objects associated with each of the parent objects (preferably, each of the parent objects *whose Description has changed*) and then copy the value from the associated parents to the children. There's multiple ways to do this, but they all follow the general "collect-filter-query-update" pattern:

1. Collect information about desired records and filter based on criteria.
2. Query for desired records.
3. Collect updated records and perform a single bulkified update.

A loose pseudocode sketch of the pattern applied to this trigger could be something like this.

```
Create a Set<Id> variable
for (each record in Trigger.new) {
    Check if Description is changed
    If it is, add record Id to set variable
}

Query for all parent records whose Ids are in Set, using a Parent-Child SOQL query to get their children as well.

Create a List<Object_2__c> variable

for (each record in query results) {
    for (each child of this record) {
        if (this record's Description_Mirror__c != parent's Description) {
            Update this record and add to list variable
        }
    }
}

update list of records
```

Using this pattern ensures that you only affect records that require changes, minimizing your use of DML and SOQL resources.